# Sharing In-Memory Cache

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Can System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache be accessed across different Console applications?

I've read about memcached but our team requires using only .Net libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [AppFabric Caching.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334364.aspx)

It will allow you to treat multiple servers/computers as nodes in a caching cluster and handle automatic replication for you.

Comment: Thanks Josh, just wondering, isn't it overkill if I only need the cache on a single server?

Can System.Runtime.Caching support that?

Thanks

Comment: Saw System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles and I think this is exactly what we need.

Answer (score 0):

An Answer for jr pineda question :
for single server best solution would be [Distributed Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.memorycacheservicecollectionextensions.adddistributedmemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) Cache which is  framework-provided implementation of IDistributedCache that stores items in memory. The Distributed Memory Cache isn't an actual distributed cache. Cached items are stored by the app instance on the server where the app is running.